# Shuffle questions in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Does anyone know how to shuffle the questions in a Quiz, I'm trying to make with a list of questions using generate and but when I try to put the method `shuffle()` it gives an error.

Here's an example:

```
class Question {
  final int id, answer;
  final String question;
  final List<String> options;

  Question({this.id, this.question, this.answer, this.options});
}

const List sample_data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "question":
        "Flutter is an open-source UI software development kit created by ______",
    "options": ['Apple', 'Google', 'Facebook', 'Microsoft'],
    "answer_index": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "question": "When google release Flutter.",
    "options": ['Jun 2017', 'Jun 2017', 'May 2017', 'May 2018'],
    "answer_index": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "question": "A memory location that holds a single letter or number.",
    "options": ['Double', 'Int', 'Char', 'Word'],
    "answer_index": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "question": "What command do you use to output data to the screen?",
    "options": ['Cin', 'Count>>', 'Cout', 'Output>>'],
    "answer_index": 2,
  },
];
```

I create a new button with every 4 options, when I run this the options never change its place, so I wanted to shuffle the place of the options.

How the buttons are made:

```
SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding),
            ...List.generate(
              question.options.length,
              (index) => Option(
                index: index,
                text: question.options[index],
                press: () => _controller.checkAns(question, index),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: where do you call shuffle and what's the error?

Comment: I putted at List.generate(
              question.options.length,
              (index) => Option(
                index: index,
                text: question.options[index],
                press: () => _controller.checkAns(question, index),
              ).toList().shuffle();

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question where you call `shuffle()` or what error you get, but the following may still be useful.

If you have a class `Question` as defined above, and a class `Quiz` defined as:

```
class Quiz {
  final List<Question> questions;
  Quiz(this.questions);
}
```

You can generate a `Quiz` with a shuffled list of `Question`s like this:

```
const questions = [ ... ];  // create some questions
final shuffledQuestions = List.from(questions)..shuffle();
final quiz = Quiz(shuffledQuestions);
```

Some things to notice here:

- We cannot call `questions.shuffle()`. `questions` is `const` meaning it is a compile time constant and can never change during the lifetime of the program. `shuffle()` modifies the list it is called on, rather than creating a new, shuffled instance of the list. If you try to call `question.shuffle()` you will get an `Unsupported operation` error.
- Since `shuffle()` returns `void`, if we write `final shuffled = questions.shuffle();`, `shuffled` will have a type of `void` (which means it cannot be used anywhere). Instead, we use `..` (the "cascade" operator). This does essentially the same thing as:

```
const questions = ...;
final shuffled = List.from(questions);
shuffled.shuffle();
final quiz = Quiz(shuffled);
```

Another thing to be careful of:
Don't shuffle your list inside a `build()` method. `build()` can be called by the framework whenever it wants to (maybe the screen has changed orientation, maybe a keyboard has appeared, etc), and that means your list will be shuffled again, and your buttons will jump around.

Instead, move the creation and shuffling of your data into a `State`s `initState()` method. This is guaranteed to be called only once which your widget "stays in the same place", regardless of rebuilds